# How do you eradicate a disease?

Tags: pandemic

What are ways you can have a disease eradicated?

Is it if you get rid of all the cubes or do you have to find a cure first?

Answer (score 11):

You must first discover the cure before you can eradicate a disease. Otherwise, some diseases could begin the game eradicated. From the [rulebook](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/25/12/251252dd-1338-4f78-b90d-afe073c72363/zm7101_pandemic_rules.pdf), page 4:

> Treat Disease
>
> > If the *last* cube of a *cured disease* is removed from the board, this disease is *eradicated*. Flip its cure marker from its “vial” side to its “0” side.
>
> Discover a Cure
>
> > [...]If no cubes of this color are on the board, this disease is now eradicated. Flip its cure marker from its “vial” side to its “0” side.

And:

> Removing the last cube of a disease that is not cured has no effect.

Comment: However, if a disease that has no cube on the board becomes cured, it immediately becomes eradicated. The order in which things are done is not important.

Comment: I believe the rules quote under Discover a Cure makes that clear.